# Script to search for a string from a file

Tags: linux, string, shell

I am able to search for a string(with some pattern) from a file using grep command manually.
But using some script, I want to take a line(each line is a string) from a file1 which has say some 100 unique lines and search each string in a different file2 and if present, output the complete line from file2

file1

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
```

file2

```
 somestring abcd somestring
 somestring somestring somestring
 somestring ijkl somestring
 somestring efgh somestring
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `grep -Fwf`:

```
grep -Fwf file1 file2
```

- `-F ->` fixed string (no regex)
- `-W ->` search for complete word
- `-f <pattern-file> ->` take patterns from a file

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
egrep -f file_one file_two
```

or

```
 grep -Ff file_one file_two
```